# Github Actions, Deploy ARM template with Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments

Tags: azure, github, github-actions, roles

i ve been trying to deploy an ARM template with Github Actions and keep falling into the same problem no matter what I tried:

> Authorization failed for template resource '...' of type
> '**Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments**'. The client '...' with
> object id '...' does not have permission to perform action
> '**Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write**' at scope
> '/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/ds-rgc/providers/Microsoft.Storage/**storageAccounts/myStorageName**/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/...'

The failure reason is obvious and I don't think it has anything to do with Github but with the application I created...:

I registered an app with Azure App Registration, created a secret and end up with the credentials object:

```
  {
    "clientId": "<GUID>",
    "clientSecret": "<GUID>",
    "subscriptionId": "<GUID>",
    "tenantId": "<GUID>",
  }
```

I added that as a secret in Github, tested the login with an action and everything worked great. The problem appeared only when I tried to assign roles in the ARM template.

*Worth mentioning that the *same template with the correct role assignments* runs perfectly from Azure Custom deployment.*

This cost me a few hours already, but honestly I cannot find a way to elevate the permissions of the app and add 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' permission or the 'User Access Administrator' role...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was too tired...

I had to go my `Subscription` (because that was the scope of my template) > `Access control (IAM)` > `Add role assignment` > find `User Access Administrator` > click `Next` > select `User, group, or service principal` > click `+Select members` > type the apps name > select it from the list > click `Select` and then  `Review + Assign`.

Done...